# issue to extract token from sub token using strtok() function in c

Tags: c

Have written following code in c

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main()
{
    char str[] = "gatway=10.253.1.0,netmask=255.255.0.0,subnet=10.253.0.0,dns=10.253.0.203";
    char name[100],value[100];
    char *token1,*token2;
    char *commasp = ", ";
    char *equ="=";

    token1 = strtok(str,commasp);

    while(token1 != NULL)
    {
        token2 = strtok(token1,equ);
        sprintf(name,"%s",token2);
        token2 = strtok(NULL,commasp);
        sprintf(value,"%s",token2);

        printf("Name:%s Value:%s\n",name,value);
        token1 = strtok(NULL,commasp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is i got only one printf like `Name:gatway   Value:10.253.1.0`. i know last `strtok()` in `while` loop followed by previous `strok()` which turns to null so token1 get null value and break the loop. Have think solution for it to not use `strtok()` in `while` loop for sub token (getting name and value) and use other method to extract name and value but it seems to lengthy code(using for or while loop for character match).So any one have batter solution to packup code in single loop.

Comment: use `strtok_r` or find '=' by `strchr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `strtok_r` instead of `strtok`.

```
char *key_value;
char *key_value_s;

key_value = strtok_r(str, ",", &key_value_s);

while (key_value) {
    char *key, *value, *s;

    key = strtok_r(key_value, "=", &s);
    value = strtok_r(NULL, "=", &s);
    printf("%s equals %s\n", key, value);
    key_value = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &key_value_s);
}

gatway equals 10.253.1.0
netmask equals 255.255.0.0
subnet equals 10.253.0.0
dns equals 10.253.0.203
```

Frankly though I think it would be easier to just look for `,` and when you find one look for `=` backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps, first parse the main string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "gatway=10.253.1.0,netmask=255.255.0.0,subnet=10.253.0.0,dns=10.253.0.203";
    char name[100],value[100];
    char *commasp = ", ";
    char *ptr[256], **t = ptr, *s = str;

    *t = strtok(str, commasp);
    while (*t) {
        t++;
        *t = strtok(0, commasp);
    }

    for (t = ptr; *t; t++) { 
        printf("%s\n", *t); 
        // now do strtok for '=' ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then parse individual pairs as before.

The above results in:

```
gatway=10.253.1.0
netmask=255.255.0.0
subnet=10.253.0.0
dns=10.253.0.203
```